# How to exclude third party app in uiActivityViewController?

Tags: objective-c

there is any option to exclude third party app. Apart from given option

```
 NSArray *excludedActivities = @[UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,UIActivityType,                                    UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                UIActivityTypePostToVimeo, UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo,]
```

Comment: how to make custom activityviewcontroller.....please any one help me..

Comment: please try it instead of you array --->  NSArray *excludedActivities = @[];

Comment: it is not possible. it need correct answer. Please any one answer me?